# how to create a proper if then else statement for pseudocode and class diagram

Tags: if-statement, pseudocode

First off I apologize for not elaborating and clarifying the question first, so I will do that right now.

I am currently trying to complete a a lab exercise (topic is on earthquakes) that requires UML class diagram and pseudocode.

one of the method required is named the determineclassification()

so for the pseudocode it is required that you have an if then else statement for the method above.

example

```
magnitude
0-3
4-6

classification
little
medium

determineclassification()

If magnitude 0 > and magnitude < 3

then

classification = little

elseif magnitude 4 > and magnitude < 6

then

classification = medium
```

and vice versa

I was wondering if the method that I am using right is the correct way to create a if-then-else statement.

Comment: logically? in a particular programming language?

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote?  It looks pretty clear.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: The one above I used is just for example (the one I am actually working on is for earthquakes), it's basically determineclassification() for a class diagram and I needed a if-then-else statement in the pseudocode, so I thought okay determineclassification() If magnitude number > and magnitude number < then class = statement (could be minor light or moderate)

Comment: I am not sure if that's how your suppose to properly do it or not, I apologize for not elaborating and clarifying the question a little more, but that's what I am looking for (pseudocode if-then-else).

Comment: @james: Please **update** your question to be your **real** question.    Please do not comment on your question.  Please **update** it to be complete, correct and current.

Comment: "I was wondering if the method that I am using right is the correct way to create a if-then-else statement."?  What's wrong with what you're doing?  What aren't you sure of?  What problem are you having?   What's not working?  What can't you do?  It seems perfect.  Please expand your question to identify something that you can't do.

Comment: "First off I apologize for not elaborating and clarifying the question first, so I will do that right now."  Doesn't help.  Not part of your question.  Delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could be a lot clearer, but since it'll look similar in most languages I'll just go with it.

```
if (age > 10 && age < 18) {
    person = young;
}
else if (age >= 18) {
    person = old;
}
```

I assume people >= 100 are *also* old, so no reason for an upper bound.  Using `< 18` and `> 17` may work if using `int` types, but it's safer and clearer just to use `>=` on the second range.

### Earthquake version:

Now that you've change it to this earthquake example, you're still messing up your **edge cases**.  Where does 3.5 fit? 4? 6?

```
determineClassification(magnitude) {
    if (magnitude < 4)
        return "little"

    if (magnitude < 6)
        return "medium"

    return "large"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty good pseudo code, there is nothing wrong in it. There is no need for an upper bound in the second `if` unless you want to create another qualifier for people whose `age > 100`, e.g. ancient or something.